# iphone sdk: prevent alearts while running process in Background

Tags: iphone, background-process

I'm developing an app where I use performSelectorInBackground to do some sync task in the background. In my code I want to be able to detect whether I'm runing in a background process. This way I can prevent alert messages which might otherwise show up.

Thanks for your help!

Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "background process", I assume you mean "background thread". To check if you're running on the main thread, try this:

```
// Some error handling code
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    // Provide some sort of UI feedback
}
else {
    // Send a message to the main thread to provide feedback
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick respons! That was it!